# How set Beyond Compare ignore summary comments .net

Tags: regex, beyondcompare

I need that Beyond Compare 4 only compare code and not summary comments like

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Instancia estática del contenedor.
    /// </summary>
    public static ComponentContainer Instance
    {
        get { return ComponentContainer._instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inicializa la instancia estática del contenedor.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (!IsInitialized)
            _instance = new ComponentContainer();
    }
```

And other code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Instancia estática del contenedor xx
    /// </summary>
    public static ComponentContainer Instance
    {
        get { return ComponentContainer._instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inicializa la instancia estática del contenedor.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (!IsInitialized)
            _instance = new ComponentContainer();yyyy
    }
```

The idea is that only the Beyond Compare show diference in the line **yyyy** and not the line **xx**.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In **Rules**, **Importance** tab, in the top where says "Unimportance", click the **plus icon**, check on **Regular expression** and write:

```
.*///.*
```